# paypal integration using php

Tags: php, paypal

i have followed the steps form the following link 
https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php to integrate paypal for my website, its working good, after successful transaction it redirect to a specified php page with a **token** and a **payerID**.... what should do with that token? i dont know what is the use of it? will it help me to process further?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration